# Rails3 Newbie Trying to Select and Iterate Through Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, spree

I'm really struggling to figure out how to iterate through some data and then 'do' something before moving on to next record.

In the following array, I need to extract the 'batch_id' and use this variable in another action. My query looks like this:

```
 data = item.line_items.map { |li| li.variant.product }
```

Output:

```
[#<Spree::Product id: 706676762, name: "60 Minute Internet Voucher", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing...", available_on: "2012-02-12 18:06:08", deleted_at: nil, permalink: "60-minute-prepaid-wifi-internet-voucher", meta_description: "", meta_keywords: "", tax_category_id: 25484906, shipping_category_id: 727197547, created_at: "2012-02-12 18:06:08", updated_at: "2012-02-21 09:16:01", count_on_hand: 9999964, batch_id: 1, is_voucher: true>, #<Spree::Product id: 569012001, name: "Ruby Baseball Jersey", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing...", available_on: "2012-02-12 18:06:08", deleted_at: nil, permalink: "ruby-baseball-jersey", meta_description: "", meta_keywords: "", tax_category_id: 25484906, shipping_category_id: nil, created_at: "2012-02-12 18:06:08", updated_at: "2012-02-20 22:04:04", count_on_hand: 1000, batch_id: 2990, is_voucher: false>]
```

I need to iterate through each record one by one, extracting the batch id for another query. Then move on to the next one. I thought something like this might do it but I can't quite get my head around it:

```
 1.upto(max_loop) do |i|
   batch_id = xxxx
   Spree.get("/api/v1/radcheck/spree_index?batch_id=#{batch_id}")
   ...
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want:

```
data.each do |prod|
  begin
    Spree.get("/api/v1/radcheck/spree_index?batch_id=#{prod.batch_id}")
  rescue
    Rails.logger.warn("Something went wrong")
  end
end
```

Comment: Think that works. Is there any way to skip in event of error. For instance if batch_id = 1 does not exist in remote query?

Comment: Almost certainly. What sort of error are we talking about? I don't know what `Spree.get` does or returns.

Comment: It shouldn't really through an error but just in case. Spree.get is an httparty call to our other application. It's basically searching for a voucher code with batch_id=x. For example, if the batch with id =x is not found at other end.

Comment: @simonmorley do a begin and rescue like try and catch in the normal C-like languages

Comment: In that case, yes, `begin-rescue-end` is what you want. See edit.

Comment: `each` is not the only way to loop. You should get familiar with the other methods of the Enumerable Module. To highlight a few by importance: `each, map, inject, select, reject , compact,each_with_index, uniq`, etc... Doint everything with each is usualy non-idiomatic and strange.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with @pedrorolo. `each` just seemed best here (although depending on what your get returns and what you do with it, `map` [for instance] may actually be better).